# Scroll (Page) transition effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

everyone.

I'm currently working on a redesign of a site and I found this [page transition really](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9-bo6AknXHrWFhETUQ4NVdUcUE) interesting and I want to replicate it, but I couldn't find any Jquery library that does this effect.

Can someone tell me how to imitate this? or does anyone knows the library?

https://theundefeated.com/features/are-vance-joseph-and-anthony-lynn-a-sign-of-change-in-the-nfl/

Answer (score 0):

you can google it for `jQuery` library.
may this link help you http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/page%20transition/